# Voice Recognition programm instantly exits code instead of listening for input

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, pyaudio

Hello i honestly dont know if this is very much a stupid question or not but i am currently learning more python and as such am following some instructions on creating a little Voice Recognition programm. Now right now i am only at a part where it recognizes what you said and prints that out as text via SpeechRecognition and such. For some reason though whenever i start the programm is gives me the first "I am listening" output and then instantly skips to the next and exits the program while a friend who i've sent the same code told me it worked fine for him and even showed me his text output. I am using Linux Mint Cinnamon 21.2 on my Laptop and my Microphone does indeed work if that helps. My friend himself used an arch distribution and the basic IDLE IDE and got it to work so i am just sitting here scratching my head like a complete amateur as to why it wont work for me. Appreciate any kind of help.

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import webbrowser
import datetime
import pywhatkit
import os
import yfinance as yf
import pyjokes
import sounddevice
import pyaudio

# listen to microphone and return audio as text

def transform():
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    r.pause_threshold = 0.8
    said = r.listen(source, phrase_time_limit = 5)
    try:
        print("I am listening")
        q = r.recognize_google(said, language="en-US", pfilter=0).lower()
        return q
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Sorry i did not understand that")
        return "I am waiting"
    except sr.RequestError:
        print("Sorry service is down")
        return "I am waiting"
    except:
        return "I am waiting"

transform()
```

I've tried several IDEs and even ran it in console expecting a text output of what i say.

Comment: Your function returns the response from Google, but you simply throw it away.  How would you know if it worked?  I suspect you wanted `print(transform())`.

Comment: With that change it just prints all 3 except returns and still instantly skips the waiting for any kind of input.

Comment: Are you sure you are saying something within 5 seconds of launching the script?  It won't wait forever.  Perhaps you should delete the `phrase_time_limit` for now.  And it can't print all three except returns.  You should show us the exact output you get.

Comment: i have only added that afterwards actually to see if it buys me more time, i am saying something and what it basically does is it instantly outputs both the "I am listening" and the "Sorry i did not understand that" message at the exact same time. it just skips doing anything no matter if i say something upon pressing run or wait 1-3 seconds. The code has perfectly worked for someone else before it only seems to do that when i run it. What i am saying is i press run and it then waits always a different amount of time before it instantly outputs both of the messages at once and exits the code.

Comment: If you `print(said)`, do you see anything?

Comment: just to confirm out of sheer stupidity on my part, where am i meant to implement this? i just tried it in either except clause, inside the function call and after the function call. Each time it would respond with "NameError: name 'said' is not defined"

Comment: Immediately after you create it -- after `said = r.listen...`.  That's the only place it exists.  I'm hoping it will tell you whether it actually captured any bytes or not.

Comment: adding it right below where i create it now gives me a new output right before the "I am Listening" it says <speech_recognition.audio.AudioData object at 0x7f8bf12f4b50> right after it just exits immediately as before. Tried several times speaking at several different times though sadly no change in the overall result.

Comment: My next suggestion is to get rid of the `try`/`except` blocks so you can actually SEE what error you're getting.  Right now, you have no clue.  As a rule, you should never use try/except blocks during development, because they hide errors.  Exceptions are great for production code, but are often a bad idea during development and debugging.

Comment: that atleast right now hasnt changed anything in the output besides removing the except outputs. No error messages as i know the code works as a friend of mine tried it on his machine with no errors. ive also tested my microphone again and it pics up anything i say fine.

Comment: I thought you said you were seeing the strings from one of the exception blocks!  Are you speaking English?

Comment: That changes completely at random. Sometimes it gives me the UnknownValueError message sometimes it doesnt, As i have also described in the post itself, a friend of mine tested the code himself since i wasnt getting any actual error messages and it worked fro them while it automatically exits the code with either just the first "I am listening" message or both that and the first except message. I have been trying to figure out for days why the code just wont respond with any output on my end while it works for others. My Hardware is working fine and yet it just refuses to work.

Comment: Is it possible you have multiple microphones?  There are instructions on their git page on how to print the list of recognized microphones.  What does `len(said.frame_data)` say?  That tells you how much audio it captured.

Comment: Just wanted to apologize for the lack of communication on my part as i sadly have to stop the project due to other work just taking up the rest of the time but i really appreciate all the help thus far. Thank you for trying to help me fix this :)